# Convert a Javascript array into a readable string

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

If you have an array of strings in JavaScript / JQuery:

```
var myStrings = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"];
```

...what is the most **elegant** way you have found to convert that list to a readable english phrase of the form:

> "item1, item2, item3 and item4"

The function must also work with:

```
var myStrings = ["item1"]; // produces "item1"
var myStrings = ["item1", "item2"]; // produces "item1 and item2"
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Like this:

```
a.length == 1 ? a[0] : [ a.slice(0, a.length - 1).join(", "), a[a.length - 1] ].join(" and ")
```

Comment: All in a single line! I'm impressed! Thanks for a great answer.

Comment: You can shorten it slightly by using `slice`'s support for negative indices: `a.length == 1 ? a[0] : [ a.slice(0, -1).join(", "), a[a.length - 1] ].join(" and ")`